# How can I set the TimeDelay to next day @ 5am in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to run code in `func applicationDidEnterBackground` and want to set the timeDelay to be next day @ 5 am.

IE: if the user exits the app on Jan. 1st at 10 pm, I want the `timeDelay` to be Jan 2nd at 5 am.

Code below:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        submitBackgroundTasks()
      }
      
      func submitBackgroundTasks() {
        // Declared at the "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers" in info.plist
        let backgroundAppRefreshTaskSchedulerIdentifier = "bundle ID here"
        let timeDelay = 10.0

        do {
          let backgroundAppRefreshTaskRequest = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: backgroundAppRefreshTaskSchedulerIdentifier)
            backgroundAppRefreshTaskRequest.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: timeDelay)
          try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(backgroundAppRefreshTaskRequest)
          print("Submitted task request")
        } catch {
          print("Failed to submit BGTask")
        }
      }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is changing the date to the next day:

`let changedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!`

This changed the date from Jan. 1 at 10 pm to Jan. 2 at 10 pm. We have the correct date, but we need to set the time to 5 am:

`let changedTimeAndDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 5, minute: 0, second: 0, of: changedDate)!`

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. This gives me a date, not a timeInterval. I could possibly do this ```let timeInterval = changedTimeAndDate.timeIntervalSinceNow``` to convert it right?

Comment: @Simbeul you are using the delay to calculate and create a date object so what does it matter if you instead get a date object directly?

Comment: @Joakim, if I use ```changedTimeAndDate``` in ```backgroundAppRefreshTaskRequest.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: changedTimeAndDate)``` it throws me the following error: ```Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')```...

Comment: @Simbeul think that through one more time. If you have a Date object then why would you need to create a Date object?